# Как вписать команду в открытое CMD?

Tags: python

Мне нужно как-то написать команду (допустим cd *папка*) в открытую командую строку через python
вот код:

```
import os

def openCmd(): #данная функция привязана к кнопке tkinter
    os.startfile("cmd.exe") #открытие cmd через python
    """теперь мне тут нужно как-то написать в это открытое cmd команду, это возможно?"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать модуль `keyboard` и с помощью него вводить команду. Пример(в нем открываем диск `С:\\`, можно вводить любую другую команду):

```
import keyboard
import os
from time import sleep


def openCmd():  # данная функция привязана к кнопке tkinter
    os.startfile("cmd.exe")  # открытие cmd через python
    sleep(1)  #задержка
    keyboard.write(r"cd C:\\")  # пишем команду
    keyboard.press("Enter")  # жмем enter, чтобы команда выполнилась
```

Comment: А если фокус будет утерян?

Comment: спасибо, это работает. я даже не знал, что такая библиотека существует

Answer (score 2):

модуль `os` вам не поможет. Используйте модуль `subprocess`. Например так

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

p = Popen('cmd.exe', stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
out,err = p.communicate(input=b'dir\n')
print(out.decode())
```

Comment: А почему не подойдёт `os.system()`?

Comment: os.system() исполнит только одну команду и завершится возвратив только код возврата но не вывод результата